# iPad app only shows black screen after updating to iOS4 SDK

Tags: objective-c, ipad, opengl-es, crash, ios4

I just opened an iPad app I'd been working on and it was working fine, until now. I open it and the screen remains black, even after it's loaded! It's an OpenGL and I just downloaded the iOS4 SDK. I also added a provisioning profile. Would any of these changes result in a completely black screen with no error for no reason at all?

It loads the MainWindow.xib but doesn't show it. It's thinking but doesn't register touch events. All this was working until now.

Comment: please post some code or error messages and/or try to debug it.

Comment: First: There are NO ERROR MESSAGES.
Second: This is for an iPad app, so what do you mean take out your hard disk?

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
open your MainWindow.xib with Interface Builder
select the window
in Window Attributes check Visible at Launch and Full Screen at Launch.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on the iPhone. Install an adhoc or debug build by dragging into iTunes or via Xcode organizer = blank screen. Install via Xcode debugger - works fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Dane.**

I know **nearly nothing** about iPhone/iPod/iPad development, but i think this forum topic might be useful.

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/51028-ios4-black-screen-after-updating-sdk.html

And if not. I suppose Apple has also released the iPad simulator along with iOS4 SDK, try debugging your app there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

"Solution: open your MainWindow.xib with Interface Builder select the window in Window Attributes check Visible at Launch and Full Screen at Launch." - Ivan

Yeah, This is what I did to fix it. It wasn't required before but for some reason now it is. I told apple about this in an error report about 3 weeks ago. But, thanks anyway.