# Universal application has black iPad screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I've just finished my app for iPhone and it is working fine.  I now want to make the app universal but am getting a black screen when running it on the iPad simulator.  Here is what I have done so far:

- When electing to make universal, I allowed xCode to create my "-iPad" version of my main nib;  Therefore, I have MainWindow.xib for iPhone and MainWindow-iPad.xib for iPad.  I have checked my plist file and have confirmed that both entries are present
- Have double checked each UI component in the new iPad version to make sure all connections are made identically to the iPhone version.  I also double check that the classes are correct
- I have made sure that the "visible at launch" and "full screen at launch" options are selected
- I read somewhere that removing the "-" worked for someone and have tried renaming my nib and plist entries

I am assuming that my app would then load the proper nib.  Obviously I'm either wrong or have some configuration not right

On the other hand, if I need to make some change in my didFinishLoadingWithOptions to force they selection between my nibs - well I must admit I don't know how to accomplish this either.

Thanks!

Comment: If the nib can't be found, I believe the app will crash. Maybe a stupid question, but have you tried truncating your cache? I have had a similar problem in the past and believed thats how I fixed it. Does the startup image show? Could this link help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128537/ipad-app-only-shows-black-screen-after-updating-to-ios4-sdk ?

Comment: The app is not crashing, but has a black screen.  I have previously reviewed the post that you linked to in your comment which led me to checking the "visible at launch" option for the main window.  As far as truncating the cache, I have not tried this and I do not know how to go about this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after much trial and error, I have gotten this to work; Although, I'm not quite sure which exact steps solved the problem, I have a sneaking feeling it was some of the settings I had for the versioning of the app.

I created a new test app for iPhone and then converted it to iPad.  Of course this worked unlike my app.  I then compared everything I could think of between the apps.  I changed the supported version from 3.1 to 4.0 on the Target -> Summary tab.  I then check my build settings and changed everything in there to 4.0 as well. Finally, for each .xib file I set the deployment to "Project SDK Version (iOS 4.3) and the Development to "Interface Builder 3.1" because that is what my test app was set to.  To be honest, I don't even recall altering these or do I really even know if this has an impact all I know is that I did change them as described.  Did a project clean, reset the simulator and now it is working.  I'm wondering if it was the 3.1 was too early for the iPad...

Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the app doesn't crash, than it means it can find the black screen.
Truncating the cache is done in Product -> Clean and also what you could try is "Reset" on the iOS simulator.

Further more, what you could check is if the "view" is linked correctly in your nib. (see image).
[image: Linking of view for File's Owner]

Comment: OK, I've done the product -> Clean, I've reset the simulator, I've once again rechecked my connections in IB.  All connections in my iPhone nib "MainWindow.xib" are identical to my iPad nib "MainWindow-iPad.xib.  Since this is my main "screen", I don't have a view, I have a Window which is properly connected to my appDelegate.  I still cannot get the iPad to display the my first view, it is still black.

Comment: If you are comfortable with it, put it on dropbox and share it with me and I'll try to have a look tonight (GMT+2).